# jquery.cookie plugin not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, cookies

Windows 10, Codeigniter 3, wamp 3.
In order to resolve a regenerating csrf issue, I need to get a couple of cookie values with jquery. I have jquery.cookie.js latest version installed and I can see it in developer tools. I'm using the following code snippet:

```
 var csrf = $.cookie('csrf_token_name');
    console.log(csrf);
```

but the console shows it as undefined. I know that is wrong because I can get the value via php. Why might that be?

Comment: did you create cookie before getting it's value?

Comment: what is the name of the cookie that is set in codeigniter config? Inspect the actual page cookies in browser dev tools also to see what is there

Comment: the cookie name, using

Comment: the cookie name, using '$this->security->get_csrf_token_name()' is 'csrf_test_name' Not sure how that helps